Solo top-roping: use static or dynamic rope?
I'd like to spend a lot of time on a specific rock climbing route. My plan is to do a lot of repetitions in order to be able to red-point it. It's a sport route and is mostly vertical (slight or no overhang).
I chose top-rope soloing both because I don't want to annoy my belayer and because I want to try something new. I'll use grigri and/or micro-traction for protection.
Should I use static or dynamic rope? Are both options acceptable from the point of view of safety?
I imagine static rope could be dangerous in case I forget to shorten the slack. Maybe a dynamic rope could get dangerous if it gets damaged by multiple falls using micro-traction.

Both you and your anchor will be much happier with a dynamic rope. All ropes may get wear on them, so you have to keep an eye on that.

There is a big difference between using a grigri (which relies on you taking in slack all the time) and using a micro traction (which will auto-take, so there should always be no slack). So IMO, the answer will depend on which of these two you'll actually use.

NEVER fall onto a toothed cam device such as a Traxion (and certainly not the smaller-radius micro version).  Use a Shunt or similar to be kind to your rope.

In general, you could use both. I have been route setting from a static rope, which is basically like top rope solo. Falling with little slack is uncomfortable, but safe. However, given that on top roping you will not ascend the rope, I would use a dynamic rope which makes your catch much softer.
Regarding damaging the rope with a micro traxion, there have been experiments and it is basically impossible to damage the rope if there is not an excessive amount of slack.

(source bergundsteigen #126)

I have finally chosen this answer for my specific situation where I can ensure there is never any slack in the rope (using croll + µ-traction). Ruled out grigri for that reason. Other situations may call for other solutions, I guess.

I am gonna assume you know the differences of using static and dynamic ropes in general-- and that semi static ropes exist in the middle as an option.
As the other person said its possible to use any of the options to top rope solo.  That said I personally would not recommend a static line.  So much can go wrong, and imo the chance of a not quite short enough fall injuring or killing you is a lot more likely than of decking or other dynamic rope issues.  But if you wanna apply the general soloist mantra of "just don't make a horrific mistake" then yeah it can totally be done.
Some people prefer static ropes but prefering something doesn't equal safer from issues to go wrong, as we all know. You MUST have no//almost zero slack in a static system, a few foot fall can rupture organs if the forces hit you wrong, you are basically decking on the ropes//harness everytime if you wanna think of it that way.
I can't personally think of an advantage to using static ropes though, beyond it being cheaper than dynamic ropes setup or in a niche environment.  And again there are semi static ropes in the middle-- below is a link to a discussion of the same question a few years ago for more points of view. Note that many people don't fully distinguish low stretch aka semi static rope from static, anything in that 3%+ range is gonna be semi static as I called it.
https://www.mountainproject.com/forum/topic/121165361/toproping-solo-dynamic-or-static
